# Printing of a character in C? Why is it strange?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I am trying to print a character in C using malloc/free combination.  The  results are  strange, and I cannot figure out  the reason:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h> 
# include <netdb.h> 
# include <unistd.h>
# include <sys/time.h>

struct myStruct
{
  char* word;
  int num;
};

void func_3(struct myStruct Input){

  struct myStruct* addr; 
  addr = &Input;
  addr = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
  (&Input) -> num = 7;
  (&Input) -> word = "some stuff here";
  printf("This is Input word %s\n", (&Input) -> word);
} 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct myStruct myStruct_ptr;
  struct myStruct aStruct; 
  func_3(aStruct);

  printf("This is my struct's word: %c", aStruct.word);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
This is Input word some stuff here
This is my struct's word: /
```

This does not make sense to me why it prints this forward slash.  I know  that there may be other solutions to accomplish the same goal of printing this.  HOWEVER, this is a distilled version  of a very large file, and I need to know WHY this is happening.  An alternative solution will not help me, unfortunately.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I got a dollar sign: http://codepad.org/QFBzVOpO

Comment: BTW, bad name  `myStruct_ptr;` because it is not a pointer

Comment: You print the address of `word` field instead of it's content. Use `*aStruct.word` construction (or `aStruct.word[0]`) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### I have fixed your code. Please see my comments.

See the output here: https://ideone.com/IP2AR1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct myStruct
{
  char* word;
  int num;
};

void func_3(struct myStruct *Input){
  Input->num = 7;                                         // <- edit struct member
  Input->word = "some stuff here";                        // <- edit struct member
  printf("This is Input word %s\n", Input->word);
} 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct myStruct aStruct;
  func_3(&aStruct); // <- pass here

  printf("This is my struct's word: %s\n", aStruct.word); // <- print char array
  printf("This is my struct's word: %c", *aStruct.word);  // <- print first char


  return 0;
}
```

### Your old code:

```
void func_3(struct myStruct Input){                      // <- pointer needed

  struct myStruct* addr;                                 // <- not used
  addr = &Input;
  addr = malloc(sizeof(struct myStruct));
  (&Input) -> num = 7;                                   // <- not being saved
  (&Input) -> word = "some stuff here";                  // <- not being saved
  printf("This is Input word %s\n", (&Input) -> word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `func_3` passes its argument by value, not by pointer.  This means that, when you call `func_3(aStruct)`, it copies the contents of aStruct to a brand new `myStruct` object.  Then `func_3` initializes it.  Finally it returns to `main`, throwing away its brand new copy, leaving you with the original undefined contents of `aStruct`

The solution is to change `func_3` to `void func_3(struct myStruct* Input)`

Answer (score 1):

The structs are copied by value in function arguments; it means that you are changing a copy of `aStruct`; the original remains uninitialized. Your function also leaks memory (`malloc`) and has generally other issues with pointer use.

Also, you are printing the "word" as `%c` instead of `%s`; this will often print the first byte of the pointer value, but it is actually possibly undefined behaviour since the pointer does not have to be compatible with a char.

You should pass the `func_3` a pointer to the struct instead of the actual struct:

```
void func_3(struct myStruct *input){
    input->num = 7;
    input->word = "some stuff here";
    printf("This is Input word %s\n", input->word);
} 


int main(void)
{
    struct myStruct aStruct; 
    func_3(&aStruct);

    printf("This is my struct's word: %s", aStruct.word);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`aStruct` is not a pointer. You can't use `malloc` in this function.

`aStruct.word` is a POINTER to first element of string. Use `*aStruct.word` or `aStruct.word[0]` . `func_3` CHANGE element `Input`, so you must use `*Input` and `func_3(&aStruct);` .

Show this code:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h> 

struct myStruct
{
  char* word;
  int num;
};

void func_3(struct myStruct *Input){
  (Input) -> num = 7;
  (Input) -> word = "some stuff here";
  printf("This is Input word %s\n", (Input) -> word);
} 


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  struct myStruct myStruct_ptr;
  struct myStruct aStruct; 
  func_3(&aStruct);

  printf("This is my struct's word: %c", *aStruct.word);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because in `void func_3(struct myStruct Input)` `Input` is only a copy of  `aStruct`.
`aStruct` is not initialized,so its values are undefined.